# Does k8sattributes processor add labels/annotations of the data source or the metrics

Tags: open-telemetry, prometheus-node-exporter, open-telemetry-collector

Hi OpenTelemetry developers/enthusiasts,

I have a basic question about the k8sattributes processor that is part of otel collector.
We have a system where there is a pod
**kube-state-metrics**
emitting metric
**kube_pod_container_restarts_total**
about another pod
**customer-pod**

I would like to get the labels and annotations of the **customer-pod** as part of the metric and add them to the metric labels
Is k8sattributes processor designed to do this or does it add only the labels/annotations of metrics source (i.e, **kube-state-metrics**) in this case

(https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/k8sattributesprocessor)

I would appreciate if you have any ideas or answers on the above question.